# How: scrollable large images, centered small image,

Tags: html, css

No matter what I try, I cannot manage to find the proper CSS for the behaviour below:

**A:** Larger-than-window images show the upper left of the image and allow scrolling to see the rest of it.
*(Important: the parent's `DIV` background is covered, but should be visible on images with transparency — even if you scroll.)*

**B:** Smaller-than-window images are horizontally and vertically centered, the parent `DIV` covers the whole window.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **line-height** property turned out to be the base for solving the problem. Not sure if this is a hack, but it works.

```
.mainContainer {
  text-align: center;
}
#mydiv {
  line-height: 100vH;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to center the smaller image inside the parent `div`, you can use `display:flex` for the parent `div`. Then set the `justify-content` and `align-items` to **center**. Here is a workaround,

```
    #mydiv {
        overflow: auto;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height:500px;    
    }
    .mainContainer{   
        width:500px;   
        height:500px;    
        background-color:#000;    
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-size:cover;
    }
```

Replace the small image with [this](https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/120227147/m%3D2048/c8146e58d307b990fe1b44e0ab5387b2) to check how it works with a large image.

```
  <div class="mainContainer">
      <div id='mydiv'>
         <img src='https://i1.wp.com/www.rceshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/samples.png?fit=480%2C400' />
      </div>
  </div>
```

PS: Change the width and height of the parent `div` to the required screen size of yours. Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm not sure why, but it didn't work for me. Maybe because the height and the width of the window is flexible.